# Converting int[] to byte: How to look at int[] as it was byte[]?

Tags: c#, types, int, byte

To explain: I have array of ints as input. I need to convert it to array of bytes, where 1 int = 4 bytes (big endian). In C++, I can easily just cast it and then access to the field as if it was byte array, without copying or counting the data - just direct access. Is this possible in C#? And in C# 2.0?

Comment: Is your application going to be running on a platform which is natively big endian? If not then you'll need to copy the bytes to do the conversion at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using unsafe code:

```
int[] arr =...
fixed(int* ptr = arr) {
    byte* ptr2 = (byte*)ptr;
    // now access ptr2[n]
}
```

If the compiler complains, add a `(void*)`:

```
    byte* ptr2 = (byte*)(void*)ptr;
```

Comment: Just tested it, and the compiler doesn't complain. (At least using C#4)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a byte[] 4 times the size of your int[] lenght.
Then, you iterate trough your integer array & get the byte array from:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(int32);
```

Next you copy the 4 bytes from this function to the correct offset (i * 4) using Buffer.BlockCopy.

[BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) 
[Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class.  You could iterate through the array of `int`, and call [`BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) to get a `byte[4]` for each one.

Comment: There is no way to access data without copying it. In fact, "access" and "copy" are essentially synonymous in this context. Even just `i` as an rvalue, the minimum possible way to access a variable, copies its value.

Comment: @David no, `ref i` doesn't copy the value :p

Comment: A new allocation per read is pretty expensive, and unfortunately `BitConverter` doesn't offer an overload that reuses an existing array.

Comment: @MarcGravell Then what does it do with the value exactly? The only thing you can do with a value in a location other than a register is copy it. (In how many places was the value before you accessed it? In how many places is it as you access it? If the second number is greater than the first, that's a copy.)

Comment: @David the alternative is to take the address (hence `ref`) - this is actually a serious point, as in the case of a `struct` you can use `ref` to pass the address to a method, and then inside the method access members and call methods, without ever copying the value. This approach is common in XNA where `struct`s are common to avoid GC.

Comment: Oh please. While technically David is right(`int` doesn't have any members after all), it's obvious that the OP talked of having a complete copy of the array, and not temporary copies of individual values in CPU registers and the like.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I know, I know. I'd have to say that the bit-shifting approach you mention would be preferable. BitConverter.GetBytes is less efficient in most cases (shifting doesn't allocate a new array each call)

Comment: @CodeInChaos Whether the code makes complete copies of the array or not and whether the copies in CPU registers are temporary or not are all implementation details that are not exposed at the C# level. Ultimately, the value has to be copied to be used in any way. The issue is just *when* it's copied, not whether. If you push a value in a register, you copy it. If you pass an address, the other function copies it. It's copied either way. (And, in general, you can't even know when, where, or whether the implementation copies.) Essentially, the OP's 'requirement' is incoherent.

Answer (score 1):

If you write unsafe code, you can fix the array in memory, get a pointer to its beginning, and cast that pointer.

```
unsafe
{
  fixed(int* pi=arr)
  {
    byte* pb=(byte*)pi;
    ...
  }
}
```

An array in .net is prefixed with the number of elements, so you can't safely convert between `int[]` and `byte[]` that points to the same data. You *can* cast between `uint[]` and `int[]` (at least as far as .net is concerned, the support for this feature in C# itself is a bit inconsistent).

There is also a union based trick to reinterpret cast references, but I strongly recommend *not* using it.

---

The usual way to get individual integers from a byte array in native-endian order is `BitConverter`, but its relatively slow. Manual code is often faster. And of course it doesn't support the reverse conversion.

One way to manually convert assuming little-endian (managed about 400 million reads per second on my 2.6GHz i3):

```
byte GetByte(int[] arr, int index)
{
  uint elem=(uint)arr[index>>2];
  return (byte)(elem>>( (index&3)* 8));
}
```

I recommend manually writing code that uses bitshifting to access individual bytes if you want to go with managed code, and pointers if you want the last bit of performance.

You also need to be careful about endianness issues. Some of these methods only support native endianness.

Comment: The bit shifting is very well noted. In particular, some platforms don't even allow unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in type-safe managed code is to use:

```
byte[] result = new byte[intArray.Length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(intArray, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
```

That doesn't quite do what I think your question asked, since on little endian architectures (like x86 or ARM), the result array will end up being little endian, but I'm pretty sure the same is true for C++ as well.

If you can use `unsafe{}`, you have other options:

```
unsafe{
  fixed(byte* result = (byte*)(void*)intArray){
    // Do stuff with result.
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `BlockCopy` uses native endianness, and not little-endian. Of course the CLR typically runs on little-endian architectures, so the difference rarely matters in practice.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, yeah--quite right. My wording was a little sloppy. I really meant to contrast the little-endianness that results from his likely platform choice with the OP's requirement for a big-endian result. I've fixed the wording to make things slightly more clear.